# Wrap Native project with React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-modules

I want to use a complex native project (https://github.com/SiliconLabs/wireless-xpress) in react native and because i cant recreate the functionality, i want to try and integrate react native on the existing one but i have no idea how to implement that. I've seen some examples on how to create native modules in ios and android but this project is too big to wrap my head around.
The project uses bluetooth low energy to connect to a board on custom hardware and use a terminal via phone.

Comment: I think you need to use the source code of this project to create an android native module for react-native . there is more info [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) .

Comment: Yeah i need to export all the methods of native to js i think? whenever i see native code my brain explodes but i agree. thanks mate

Comment: np . I would love to help you create a repo for react-native but unfortunately, I don't have the necessary tools to debug and test . I'm afraid you have to DIY it but don't worry most of the time it's easier than you think when you get into it. good luck